# Yahtzee score card — what is the term for a “full house”

Tags: translation

I'm teaching my mother-in-law how to play [Yahtzee](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yahtzee) so she can more easily join us when we have a family gathering.  She's visiting the USA.

Most things I explained easily enough using Google Translate.  But the term [“full house”](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_poker_hand_categories#Full_house) shows only literal translations.  Does Mandarin (PRC)  have a well-known term for this scoring pattern?

The other thing that left me scratching my head was “chance”.  I had to explain at length.  What's a good simple name for this?

---

Now, I’d like to make a nice sheet that extends the printed score card to the left, which I'll attach using a paper clip.  Rather than a separate card of notes, this will essentially be a translation of the labels column.  I’m doing this in illustrator and will make the PDF available on the web when I’m done.

So, if anyone would care to note good sound translations for the other items, I’d be interested in those too.  (I posted the linked items as separate questions)

- 3 of a kind
- 4 of a kind
- Full House
- [Small Straight](https://chinese.stackexchange.com/questions/22395/yahtzee-score-card-sm-and-lg-straight) (sequence of 4)
- Large Straight (sequence of 5)
- [Chance](https://chinese.stackexchange.com/questions/22397/yahtzee-scorecard-well-chosen-word-for-chance)
- Yahtzee! (5 of a kind)  (I found the phonetic transcription on the [Zh Wikipedia stub](https://zh.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E5%BF%AB%E8%89%87%E9%AA%B0%E5%AD%90))

---

## Completed

Here is the final project.  Details and files are posted on [my page](http://www.dlugosz.com/zeta/?p=428).  Any further input is still appreciated.
[image]

Comment: http://baike.baidu.com/view/989497.htm explains these terms, e,g. full house:  一种三颗一样的骰子及一种二颗一样的骰子,

Comment: Would love to have the file you made for this as I would like to teach my parents how to play Yahtzee. Tried clicking on your link but I couldn’t access it. Thank you

Comment: @JanFong-Lee if you can communicate an address, I'll email the file or share it on Google Drive or something.

Answer (score 8):

翻译参考:

UPPER SECTION 上半部
Aces 一点
Twos 二点
Threes 三点
Fours 四点
Fives 五点
Sixes 六点
TOTAL SCORE 总点数
BONUS 赠点
TOTAL 上半部小计

LOWER SECTION 下半部
3 of a kind 三同花/点
4 of a kind 四同花/点
Full House 葫芦
Small Straight 小(四)顺
Large Straight 大(五)顺
YAHTZEE "压死" 五同花/点
Chance 机会
YAHTZEE BONUS 压死赠点
TOTAL 下半部小计
TOTAL 上半部小计
GRAND TOTAL 总计

Comment: I guess 葫芦 is the transliteration of the Japanese pronunciation of Full.

Comment: I like 葫芦 after looking up a picture and especially after hearing my mother-in-law pronounce it.

Answer (score 2):

There are two common Chinese equivalent terms for "full house"

- 葫芦（葫蘆）: Literally means gourd. This term is more common in Mainland China.
- 夫佬：There isn't an English equivalent for this term. It is basically the transliteration of "Full House" in Chinese. It is more common in Hong Kong and Macau.