# Yahtzee score card — sm and lg straight?

Tags: meaning

This is part of [this set](https://chinese.stackexchange.com/questions/22196/yahtzee-score-card-what-is-the-term-for-a-full-house), where I also posted my update.

My wife, who is a native Chinese speaker, gave me the following:

```
sm.straight is 小顺
lg.straight is 大顺
```

but when I look up [小顺](https://translate.google.com/#zh-CN/en/%E5%B0%8F%E9%A1%BA) or [顺](https://translate.google.com/#zh-CN/en/%E9%A1%BA) by itself, it doesn't seem to have anything to do with (noun) sequence.  What am I missing here?

It shows me words like *obedience*, *happiness*, and *submissiveness*, with translations that may use 顺 alone or with a longer string of characters.

This dictionary doesn’t show a noun *sequence* or anything like that.

Answer (score 7):

[汉典](http://www.zdic.net/z/28/js/987A.htm) shows the following information.

> ● 顺
>
> （順）
>
> shùn 　ㄕㄨㄣˋ
>
> 1. 趋向同一个方向，与“逆”相对：～风。～水。～境。～水推舟。～风使舵。
> 2. 沿，循：～城街。～理成章。～藤摸瓜。
> 3. **依次往后：～序。～次。**
> 4. 随，趁便：～便。～势。～手牵羊。
> 5. 整理：理～。～修（整理修治）。
> 6. 服从，不违背：～从。～应。孝～。温～。
> 7. 适合，不别扭：～适。～情。～眼。～差（chā）。
> 8. 姓。
>
> 汉英互译
>
> ◎ 顺
>
> arrange　　　**in sequence**　　　in the same direction as　　　obey　　　**put in order**　　　suitable